# How to update a field in a column on MS SQL after making sure other fields are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table is here for more clarity:

[image: Table is here for more clarity]

What I am trying to do is:
- Look for every single entry in [PayupName] that has the word 'Nominal', and then, deduct the [payup(bcp)] value of that entry from the value of [payup(bcp)] of all other values listed under PayupName, which are '85k Max Loan amount', '110k Max Loan Amount', and '125k Max Loan Amount', where:

```
- [RecordDate] is the same
- [Investor] is the same
- [Product] is the same
- [MinCoupon] is the same
- [Maxcoupon] is the same
```

Update the value of payup(bcp) where, in this case, the payup name is 85k max loan, to 165.93-102.3855 = 63.5445

I need the query to do the same for all other values available. 
It's important to point out that there are a lot of different entries for RecordDate, Product, Investor, MinCoupon, and MaxCoupon.

Here is what I have so far, which is only working on one specific entry. 
Basically, I need to do this for all entries without hard coding it.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @my_variable DECIMAL(12,8);
SET @my_variable = 
                ((SELECT    [Payup(bcp)]
                FROM [MortgagePipeline].[dbo].[PayUps]
                WHERE 
                        Payupname = '85k Max Loan Amount'
                        AND product = '30-year'
                        AND Mincoupon = '3.875'
                        AND recorddate = '2019-11-21')
                        -
                (SELECT     [Payup(bcp)]
                FROM [MortgagePipeline].[dbo].[PayUps]
                WHERE 
                        Payupname = 'NOMINAL'
                        AND product = '30-year'
                        AND Mincoupon = '3.875'
                        And recorddate = '2019-11-21'))
                        *100
                        ;

UPDATE [MortgagePipeline].[dbo].[PayUps]
Set [payup(bcp)] = @my_variable
WHERE Payupname = '85k Max Loan Amount'
                        AND product = '30-year'
                        AND Mincoupon = '3.875'
                        AND recorddate = '2019-11-21'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.  It doesn't make sense to put this in as variables.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`?

```
UPDATE pu
    SET [payup(bcp)] = pu.[payup(bcp)] + pun.[payup(bcp)]
    FROM [MortgagePipeline].[dbo].[PayUps] pu JOIN
         (SELECT pun.*
          FROM [MortgagePipeline].[dbo].[PayUps] pun
          WHERE pun.Payupname = 'Nominal'
         ) pun
         ON pun.product = pu.product AND
            pun.Mincoupon = pu.Mincoupon AND
            pun.recorddate = pu.recorddate AND
    WHERE pu.Payupname <> 'Nominal';
```

Comment: Very close!
I would like to keep the value of payup(bcp) where payup is nominal the same. It shows 0 now. But the value of payup(bcp) for 85k is correct

Comment: @Hamza . . . That is easy to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

Updating from a self joined CTE is possible.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PayUps
> (
>   payups_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   Product varchar(30) not null,
>   Investor varchar(30) not null,
>   MinCoupon varchar(30) not null,
>   MaxCoupon varchar(30) not null,
>   RecordDate date not null,
>   PayupName varchar(30) not null,
>   [Payup(bcp)] decimal(12,8)
> );
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into PayUps 
> (product, investor, mincoupon, maxcoupon, recorddate, [Payup(bcp)], PayupName) values
>  ('30-year','A.C.M.E.','3.875','4.000','2019-11-21',100,'110k Max Loan Amount')
> ,('30-year','A.C.M.E.','3.875','4.000','2019-11-21',110,'125k Max Loan Amount')
> ,('30-year','A.C.M.E.','3.875','4.000','2019-11-21',120,'85k Max Loan Amount')
> ,('30-year','A.C.M.E.','3.875','4.000','2019-11-21', 42,'NOMINAL')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select payups_id, [Payup(bcp)], PayupName
> from [PayUps]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> payups_id | Payup(bcp)   | PayupName           
> --------: | :----------- | :-------------------
>         1 | 100.00000000 | 110k Max Loan Amount
>         2 | 110.00000000 | 125k Max Loan Amount
>         3 | 120.00000000 | 85k Max Loan Amount 
>         4 | 42.00000000  | NOMINAL
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE_PAYUPS AS
> (
>      SELECT 
>      Product,
>      Investor,
>      MinCoupon,
>      MaxCoupon,
>      RecordDate,
>      PayupName,
>      [Payup(bcp)]
>      FROM [PayUps]
>      WHERE Product = '30-year'
>        AND MinCoupon = '3.875'
>        AND RecordDate = '2019-11-21'
> )
> UPDATE maxloan
> SET maxloan.[Payup(bcp)] = (maxloan.[Payup(bcp)] - nominal.[Payup(bcp)])
> FROM CTE_PAYUPS AS maxloan
> JOIN CTE_PAYUPS AS nominal
>   ON nominal.Product = maxloan.Product
>  AND nominal.Investor = maxloan.Investor
>  AND nominal.MinCoupon = maxloan.MinCoupon
>  AND nominal.MaxCoupon = maxloan.MaxCoupon
>  AND nominal.RecordDate = maxloan.RecordDate
>  AND nominal.PayupName = 'NOMINAL'
>  AND maxloan.PayupName LIKE '[0-9]%[0-9]k Max Loan Amount'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select payups_id, [Payup(bcp)], PayupName
> from [PayUps]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> payups_id | Payup(bcp)  | PayupName           
> --------: | :---------- | :-------------------
>         1 | 58.00000000 | 110k Max Loan Amount
>         2 | 68.00000000 | 125k Max Loan Amount
>         3 | 78.00000000 | 85k Max Loan Amount 
>         4 | 42.00000000 | NOMINAL
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3fec9abba0a045632212c591b3bb6cab)*